# "System" taking up nearly 90 GB on my mac?

Tags: macbook-pro, storage

I was checking my storage one day on my Macbook Air and found that "System" took up the vast majority of my Mac. I was able to move nearly all of my files off my mac and deleted several applications to no avail. I contacted Apple support, and they told me to re-index the spotlight index and such, but nothing they did helped my situation. Has anyone had the same issue and if so, how can I fix it? (I have been told to re install the OS but wish to avoid doing such because of the fear of ruining the computer.)

[image]

Comment: ncdu /Applications/ (First install brew.sh and then brew install ncdu in Terminal)?

Comment: My iMac says system (High Sierra) is taking 88 GB. I don't know what to do.

Comment: @user2707001 What does ncdu tell me?  It reported 90 GB used.

Comment: Sanitize your local TM snapshots: `sudo tmutil thinlocalsnapshots / size urgency` (e.g `sudo tmutil thinlocalsnapshots / 10000000000 4`). Check `man tmutil`! Looks like a bug or an inconsistency in/of TM & APFS...

Comment: First, can you download a different app? macOS is notorious for giving bad readings of hard drive space. I recommend omni disk  sweeper.

Comment: I have same issue. My iMac says system is 89 GB. I ran DaisyDisk on my disk and it reported the system as 9.8 GB.  See my answer below.

Comment: "System" in this context is a bit of a catchall category for anything that doesn't belong in any more specific category. You really need some tool that can dig into what's going on in more detail (like DaisyDisk and DiskInventoryX, as the answers suggest).

Comment: @jmh : ncdu will show you the size of all the Applications in your Applications folder. From top (largest application) to bottom (smallest). Could you paste the list here so we can see where the problem actually is?

Comment: @user2707001 This wasn't my question.  I was just asking about ncdu becase I wasn't aware of that command.  I did have a similar situation but when I ran DaisyDisk it listed my system as 9.2 GB instead of 90 GB.

Comment: @Paul Highlight your drive and type cmnd-I (get info). Ignore the Available number near the top, Calculate Available by Subtracting Used from Capacity and see if you get a more realistic value.

Answer (score 1):

I'd download **DaisyDisk** from the Mac App Store. It will make a graphical mapping of everything stored on your drive. I have a similar problem and I ran it and there is no 89 GB sector on my disk. It's a little pricey at $10. A free option that does a similar task is [GrandPerspective](http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net).

Comment: Note that daisy disk trial can be downloaded from their website and can be used to find out what files are taking up space and where, but other minor features are not enabled, such as file collection and deletion through daisy disk.